# Problems with Doctrine Subqueries and Aliases

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Previously today, I asked/answered the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069362/4521733

Now I tried to create this query using Doctrine Query Builder:

```
$qb->select('sp')
    ->addSelect(
        '(SELECT COUNT(spa.id) FROM AppBundle:ProjectAttribute spa WHERE spa.project = sp.id AND spa.attribute = pa.attribute AND spa.attributeValue = pa.attributeValue) AS attributeSimilarity'
    )
    ->addSelect(
        '(attributeSimilarity * 1) AS similarity'
    )
    ->from('AppBundle:Project', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:ProjectAttribute', 'pa', 'WITH', 'p = pa.project')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Project', 'sp', 'WITH', 'p != sp')
    ->where('p = :project')
    ->setParameter(':project', $project)
    ->groupBy('sp.id')
    ->orderBy('similarity', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attributeSimilarity' in 'field list'
```

The problem is that Doctrine renames the subquerys "AS attributeSimilarity" and so on to "AS sclr_35", but doesn't rename the field names within the last addSelect.

I already tried to write all subqueries within a single addSelect. But that doesn't work at all.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Building sql queries from strings like that is just begging for a sql injection attack.

Comment: @Necoras I'm using prepared statements so, not really?